# Vbscript to get most recent unique files of certain extension

Tags: file, vbscript

I'm trying to gather a list of unique file names of a certain extension so that I can use that info as a variable in another app.

My source folder contains something similar to this:

```
C-VOL-B123.ext
C-VOL-B122.ext
D-VOL-B234.ext
D-VOL-B233.ext
E-VOL-B456.ext
E-VOL-B455.ext
Sys-VOL-B234.ext
Sys-VOL-B233.ext
```

along with many other files with different extensions.

I am trying to come up with a script that will output the following:

```
C-VOL-B123 D-VOL-B234 E-VOL-B456 Sys-VOL-B234
```

So only give the most recent unique file name (minus the B***, may start with another letter and may not by only 4 characters) for each file of a particular extension.

I've put together a script from snippets of code here and there but I've hit a road block, here is what I have so far:

```
Dim goFS  : Set goFS = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
    Dim sExt
    Dim sDir
    sExt = Wscript.Arguments(0)
    sDir = Wscript.Arguments(1)
       oLatest = Array(Nothing, Nothing)
       Dim oFile
       For Each oFile In goFS.GetFolder( sDir ).Files
    If LCase(goFS.GetExtensionName(oFile.Name)) = sExt Then
      If oLatest(0) Is Nothing Then
          Set oLatest(0) = oFile
      ElseIf oFile.DateLastModified > oLatest(0).DateLastModified Then
          Set oLatest(1) = oLatest(0)
          Set oLatest(0) = oFile
      ElseIf oLatest(1) Is Nothing or oFile.DateLastModified > oLatest(1).DateLastModified Then
          Set oLatest(1) = oFile
      End If
    End If
   Next 
   For i=0 to 1
       If Not oLatest(i) Is Nothing Then WScript.Echo oLatest(i).name
       Next
```

I'm not sure how to proceed from here and not very familiar with arrays.  I also need to point out that it may not always be the same number of "unique" files, some folders may have   2 sets of *.ext files like this:

```
C-VOL-B123.ext
C-VOL-B122.ext
D-VOL-B234.ext
D-VOL-B233.ext
```

or even 1 set of *.ext files so the output would need to be:

C-VOL-B123 D-VOL-B234 for 2

and

C-VOL-B123 for 1

Hopefully I am making sense here.  Thanks in advance for any help on this.

JMG

Comment: Would you mind formatting your question properly? It's not that hard.

Comment: OK let me ask the question now that I have given all the info I have to work with above. 

How do I determine the most recent file of each grouping of files (file starts with same name, ex. C-VOL-******.ext, all files have *-VOL-*.ext)?  There can be any number of file groups, ex. C-VOL-*.ext, D-VOL-*.ext.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally much easier to use a dictionary than an array.

```
Option Explicit

Dim fso, folder, file, ext, latest

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set latest = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Your\Path")

For Each file In folder.Files
    ext = LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(file))
    If latest.Exists(ext) Then
        If latest(ext).DateLastModified < file.DateLastModified Then
            Set latest(ext) = file
        End If
    Else
        latest.Add ext, file
    End If
Next
```

Now you can use it:

```
WScript.Echo latest("docx").DateLastModified
WScript.Echo latest("docx").Name
```

Think about what you want to happen if there is more than one file with the same extension and the same modified date. Change the solution accordingly.

- [`Dictionary` object reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4k5wbx4%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: I started with something very similar to this but it only gives me the most recent file for a given extension.  The code I provided above will give me the two most recent files for a particular extension, but there may be situations where I have 1 - 10 different groupings of files with the same extensions.  I would then want to have the most recent file of each grouping of files.

Comment: Hm. I'm not sure, mut it seems I misunderstand your "unique file name"/"per extension" requirement. So far all your sample file names have the same extension and you seem to want to group by a part of their name, and not by their extension at all. Also, what's a *"set of \*.ext files"*? Everything that starts with the same prefix (like `C-VOL-`) is a set?

Comment: Yeah sorry for the confusion but you are correct, a set\group would be two or more files that start with the same name.  So I am only looking for files of a specific extension that start with the same name and need a list of new file in each set\group.

maybe this screenshot will help, there are many more files than what you see in the screenshot, but the ones in yellow would be what I am  looking for in my output, however I'd like the output to not contain the .ext (ex. C_VOL-b003.spf would output as C_VOL-b003)

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7085/13697307454_db5a94fa84_o.png

Comment: Ah, I see. Well the approach is the same: instead of storing the extension in the dictionary, store the prefix. Dictionaries are well-suited for grouping data, the above code wouldn't need a lot of change.

Comment: You can use `For Each` to iterate the dictionary (preferred way) or its `.Keys()` method to get an array of the stored keys, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Seems like I need to first only look at the files with the extensions I am interested in, then group the files according to the characters before the _VOL and then get the latest file name from each of the groups and display them w/out the file extension (.ext) on the end.  
My problem is... I'm trying to learn how to do this by examples I've found and I am unable to find anyone with a scenario similar to mine.
Thanks again for hearing me out here and any direction or recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a reasonable plan. Use `Left()` and `InStr()` to find the substring before `-VOL` and use the resulting prefix just like I used the file extension in my answer. You really only need to change a small part of my code to make it work.